# using multimedia files in asp.net in background

Tags: asp.net

let's say i want to play an mp3 song in the background of the website alog the user's travesal between the different pages...
is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this, it will annoy users and possibly alienate your users without sound. The easiest way is to have another frame play the music. Another way is to have a popup come up and play the music [which stays up between pages].

Answer (score 1):

Within a single frameless page? I can't think of any possible straightforward solution.

Off my head, the altenatives are:
1. frames (parent frame plays the audio, child frame holds the site pages)
2. pop-up window which plays the audio
3. a single page which puts in page content via ajax and loads into the main container while the audio is played outside the container
4. use flash and puts in content via actionscript into the flash display panel

Personally, I would not recommend any of the above :P

Answer (score 0):

Multimedia is the best way to enhance the user interface of any application. In .NET there is many ways to play an Audio using any .NET technology supporting languages. One of the simple way to acheive is Multimedia Control Interface, shirtly we call it as MCI, wrapping high-level system components, such as Windows Media Player to play our audio files.

visit this link.. to get more information.. about it

http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.com/2006/11/using-cnet-play-multimedia-files-using.html

Comment: Cool, you even copypasted the typos from the article. For future citations please use the quote button. Don't post as if it are your own words.